# Do While loop deleting every other line? Should only delete those that meet the criteria

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have 3 tables that each have employee IDs and various pieces of information. Some of these tables have employees that have been terminated, while others include people that haven't been uploaded into different systems yet. I am trying to create a column on a new table that includes only employees that exist across all 3 tables.

I think there's an error in my offset line (or maybe my If/Then line?). When I put in Range("A1"), it deletes every other employee. When I put in Range("A2"), it deletes every 3rd employee.

I'm also really new to VBA, so it could be something as simple as selecting (or not selecting) "Use Relative References".

```
Sub CompareTest()
'
' CompareTest Macro
'
Sheets("Table1").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Compare").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Employee ID"
    
Do While ActiveCell <> ""
    ActiveCell.Range("A2").Select
    If ActiveCell.Value <> ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table2").Range("A2") Or _
    ActiveCell.Value <> ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table3").Range("E2") Then
    ActiveCell.Formula = ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A2").Select
    End If
Loop
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Why you compare every employee IDs on Table1 with `Sheets("Table2").Range("A2")` and `Sheets("Table3").Range("E2")`？

Comment: Welcome MaggieMay! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!

Answer (score 0):

- Use a `Dictionary` object to count the occurrences of `IDs` in three tables.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144187)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String, iR As Long
    Dim arrData, arrRes, vSht, vKey
    Dim lastRow As Long, oSht As Worksheet
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' loop through 3 tables
    For Each vSht In Array("Table1", "Table2", "Table3")
        Set oSht = Worksheets(vSht)
        lastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngData = oSht.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
        ' load data 
        arrData = rngData.Value
        For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
            sKey = arrData(i, 1)
            If objDic.Exists(sKey) Then
                objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) + 1
            Else
                objDic(sKey) = 1
            End If
        Next i
    Next
    ' populate output array
    ReDim arrRes(1 To objDic.Count, 0)
    For Each vKey In objDic.Keys
        If objDic(vKey) = 3 Then
            iR = iR + 1
            arrRes(iR, 0) = vKey
        End If
    Next
    Set oSht = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oSht = Sheets("Compare")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If oSht Is Nothing Then
        Sheets.Add.Name = "Compare"
        Set oSht = ActiveSheet
    Else
        oSht.Cells.Clear
    End If
    ' write output to sheet
    oSht.Range("A1") = "Employee ID"
    oSht.Range("A2").Resize(iR, 1).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```